# Solution of an IVP through Laplace transform

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform, initial-value-problems, inverse-laplace

Let $()$ be the solution of the initial value problem

$$y''+4y=\begin{cases} t, & 0\leq t\leq 2\\ 2, & 2<t<\infty \end{cases}.$$
Also, it is given that $$y(0)=0, y'(0)=0.$$

Given that $\alpha=y\big(\frac{\pi}{2}\big)$, show that $4\pi\alpha=0.5$ (round off to two decimal places).

I started by taking the Laplace transform of the given equation to note that
(Let $Y(s)$ be the Laplace transform of $y(t)$):
$$s^2Y(s)-sy(0)-y'(0)+4Y(s)=\int_0^2 te^{-st} dt+\int_2^{\infty}2e^{-st}dt$$
which means that
$$(s^2+4)Y(s)=-\frac{t}{s}e^{-st}\big|_0^2-\frac1{s^2}e^{-st}\big|_0^2-\frac{2}se^{-st}\big|_2^{\infty}$$
$$=-\frac2se^{-2s}-\frac1{s^2}e^{-2s}+\frac1{s^2}+\frac2se^{-2s}$$
$$=\frac1{s^2}-\frac{1}{s^2}e^{-2s}.$$
This implies that
$$Y(s)=\frac{1}{(s^2+4)}\bigg(\frac1{s^2}-\frac1{s^2}e^{-2s}\bigg).$$

How to proceed forward.

Comment: Partial fractions on $\frac{1}{(s^2+4)s^2} $ then find the inverse. The same thing multiplied by $e^{-2s}$ can be inverted using the shift theorem $f(t-p)u(t-p)=F(s)e^{-2p}$.

Comment: Now perform partial fraction decomposition. // Note that for the solution of the task you only need the first part of the function where $y''+4=t$.

Comment: Check your task description  again, it seems like a fraction got converted into a product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
Y(s)
=
K(s)-e^{-2s}K(s)
$$
where
$$K(s)=
\frac{1}{s^2(s^2+4)}
=\frac{1/4}{s^2}-\frac{1/4}{s^2+4}
$$
Using inverse Laplace table
$$
y(t)
=
k(t)
-
k(t-2)u(t-2)
$$

where
$
k(t)
=
\frac14t
-
\frac{1}{8}
\sin(2t)
$.

It follows
$y(\pi/2)=\frac14 (\pi/2)$ which is different to what is claimed?